# Capacitance of MOS capacitor vs orientation

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, cmos, solid-state-devices

**Edit** Both FETs are the same PFET with the same dimensions.

I wanted to check the capacitance of a MOS capacitor vs its orientation. I expected the gate low orientation to have greater capacitance because a channel would be formed as in typical operation.

I charged both capacitors from 0 V to 1.8 V with separate voltage sources. I plotted the integrated current (i.e. charge) from each voltage source to see the charge on each capacitor.

The gate low orientation has more overall capacitance as expected—it has more charge at the same voltage.

The linearized or small-signal capacitance is the slope of the charge plot. At higher voltages, the two charge plots are nearly parallel, which means the small signal capacitances are nearly identical. **Why is this the  case?**

In my understanding, the overlap capacitance is common to both orientations, but the gate low orientation should have a large gate-channel capacitor while the gate high orientation should have a smaller gate-bulk capacitor.

[image]
[image]

Comment: *Orientation*: do you mean **polarity** (and your circuit drawing seems to support this interpretation)?

Comment: I think either could work—why do you think polarity is more clear? I would not want someone to think I am comparing a PFET and an NFET, which are sometimes described as having opposite polarity.

Comment: It's not clear whether you've tested a P-ch or N-ch; the substrate arrow is in the wrong position. But therein lies your clue: the channel doping is a relevant parameter.

Comment: @TimWilliams both FETs are the same PFET. Same dimensions, same doping. I updated my question to make this clear.

Comment: Huh, so the arrow is not only in the wrong position but pointing the wrong direction? Yikes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in *Circuit Design, Layout, and Simulation* by Jacob Baker (section *MOSFET Capacitance Overview/Review*).

The small-signal capacitance is comparable in inversion (\$|V_{GS}| > V_{TH}\$) and accumulation (\$|V_{GS}| < 0\$) because there are mobile carriers underneath the oxide in both cases.

Taking the PMOS capacitor for example, in the familiar case of inversion, mobile holes form a channel under the oxide giving a gate-channel capacitor. In the potentially less familiar case of accumulation, mobile electrons are attracted under the gate resulting in a similar structure.

A key difference is that there is low resistance between the source/drain and channel in inversion. In contrast, in accumulation, there is no conduction of the attracted mobile electrons across the reverse biased source-bulk and drain-bulk junctions. The connection to the "plate" of the capacitor underneath the oxide is therefore through the bulk which is a longer path and higher resistance connection. The result is that the accumulation mode capacitor effectively has a large series resistance.

Baker suggests using the inversion mode capacitor to avoid the additional series resistance.

The inversion mode capacitor has an additional "feature" that it has more overall charge at the same voltage due to the formation of an inversion layer. This is a guess: inversion takes more charge because first electrons have to be repelled and only then are holes attracted—accumulation only does half of this "movement" in attracting electrons to the oxide. This may be a benefit if the  large-signal capacitance is to be maximized or a detriment from the perspective of start-up currents. The accumulation capacitor may be a better choice if it is only going to handle small signals, the series resistance is not an issue, and start-up currents are to be minimized.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the charge-vs-time plot is not a capacitance -- neither `overall` nor `small-signal`. It is just what it is, the current. dQ/dt = I(t). Therefore, your plots only prove that after 140us-160us the currents through your MOS capacitors are equal, and nothing else. As a supposedly useful exercise, you can try and solve the problem, why between 60us and 140us the current that charges Q1's MOS capacitor is noticeably less than the current that charges Q0's MOS capacitor, the VIN0/VIN1 voltage increase rates being equal.

If not for your unconventional definition of voltage polarity as `orientation`, I would write the above text as comment, but I wasted a few minutes trying to decipher your description, and, with a legitimate feeling of completion, I'm writing the answer.

+1 in advance for solving the problem, why the currents are different in the midrange.

Leaving aside the discussion of validity of your measurements and interpretation, pay attention to a formal error in your analysis of graphs.

You argue that the MOS capacitor model predicts lower capacitance for configuration 1, and your graphs do support this claim: for \$C_{MOS,0} = W(Q0)/V(VIN0)\$ and \$C_{M0S,1} = W(Q1)/V(VIN1)\$, \$C_{M0S,1} < C_{MOS,0}\$, especially at higher volages.

Now, the model does not state, at least as perceivably as it does for **integral capacities**, that for **differential capacities** \$C_{diff,MOS,0} = dW(Q0)/dV(VIN0)\$ and \$C_{diff,MOS,1} = dW(Q1)/dV(VIN1)\$ the same inequality, \$C_{diff,MOS,1} < C_{diff,MOS,0}\$, holds. By the way, the slope of your W(Q1) graph is still noticeably less that the W(Q0) slope even at higher voltages, albeit by a tiny amount.

Your graphs are not in conflict with the model, even for intuitive interpretation thereof.

Comment: The current through a capacitor is \$I = C(v) \cdot \frac{dv}{dt}\$. This differs from the basic expression with a more general \$C(v)\$ because the capacitors are non-linear. The voltage is a linear ramp, so \$\frac{dv}{dt} = A\$ and \$v = At\$. Putting that together you get \$I = C(At) \cdot A\$. The \$A\$ terms simply scale the x and y axes, but the current (i.e. slope of the charge), does reflect the linearized capacitance at a certain voltage \$v = At\$.

Comment: First, let C (MOS capacitor's capacitance) is a function of V only. With your V = A·t; I = C·(dV/dt) + V·(dC/dt) = A·C + V·(dC/dt) = A·C + V·(dC/dV)·(dV/dt) = A·C + V·(dC/dV)·A = A·(C + V·(dC/dV)) and you are back to expressing the current via the arbitrary (I mean, unknown to you) C(V). It is your I = C(At)⋅A only if dC/dV = 0, but, in general (especially with MOS capacitors), it is not the case.

Comment: I hope this explanation is sufficient to appease your confusion, so I won't bore you with additional complications of an MOS capacitor charge function in its general form (when capacitance depends not only on voltage at the current moment), in which case dC/dt = V·(∂C/∂V)·(dV/dt) + ∂C/∂t (full differential expressed via partial differentials) and calculations are simpler with primordial I = dQ/dt.

Comment: Are you saying that the capacitance is not just a function of voltage,  but also the time derivative of voltage? I can check that tomorrow by changing the ramp angle and seeing if there's a difference. I am not an expert in physics, but considering a simple capacitor with non-linear dielectric, I think the rate of change of voltage wouldn't matter until you approach the time constant of whatever is "stretching" in the dielectric which I think would be very fast (e.g. time constant of dipoles rotating).

Comment: I do not think that time dependence can be observed at us times, I mention it only for completeness. As for explanation of your seeming contradiction see updated answer.

Comment: After your latest update, I think you are saying that you do not expect the small-signal capacitance to be very different between the two configurations. So then do both configurations have a channel, or is the gate-bulk cap. the same as the gate-channel cap., or what? This is my original question.

Comment: There are two questions. One, are small signal capacitances nearly identical (irrespective to your measurements), another, are your measurement and interpretation valid. Which should I answer first? In my answer, I'm addressing the last paragraph of your Q, `In my understanding, the overlap capacitance is common to both orientations, but the gate low orientation should have a large gate-channel capacitor while the gate high orientation should have a smaller gate-bulk capacitor`.